# o365 mail sending is failing when we create meetings in o365 using API

Tags: amazon-ec2, office365, office365api

We are creating meeting in o365 using APIs from our application running in AWS. Now when o365 tries to send the meeting invitation mail to the attendees, it is failing with the following message
"Your message wasn't delivered because the recipient's email provider rejected it."

```
Accept-Language: en-IN, en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: <MA1PR01MB05367FFBBDA3D3428394F137EA940@MA1PR01MB0536.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM>
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Originating-IP: [x.x.x.x]
X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;MA1PR01MB0536;35:xxkBmbXtXVZGwsiEiilEbeHIi2ZfWIEmurkPr5sPyonpPJb4Few1njcGEXmLtoIRRPDQzZ0MGBpVxEBs5k+NHQ==
Return-Path: ravi@wizergos.onmicrosoft.com
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: bff8840d-3e84-4e15-2467-08d4f5e3332a
X-Microsoft-Antispam:
     UriScan:;BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(300000500095)(300135000095)(300000501095)(300135300095)(22001)(300000502095)(300135100095)(2017030254152)(2017082002075)(300000503095)(300135400095)(2017052603199)(2017052602031)(201703131423075)(201702281549075)(300000504095)(300135200095)(300000505095)(300135600095)(300000506095)(300135500095);SRVR:MA1PR01MB0423;
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
    1;MA1PR01MB0423;3:Xef52NLXLwX4Of/x+cHPnQu37UGGPZubrpQKrlol422+XrwEXRRTZSVc/dNSXnhf8zx/T3Ve+GWXWow34lClcPGYw2XJOww+LnbbazzBaUpH+7AZ7hxerQvITqaoRBJ+O8BwlgPm5N66JQ/x8OzvOrfEyLfy5wHMyfkpOdUQcjNjk3WwA/UqEYLnw0Bi8+sNzuRv9KYmy3e/ecsoKufxTGIxhUvkzscdXkJzmIcFxSj1U8oe7gu1ju+UfLIlRAAz;25:zlxV3kOuhuB0AiZji3QcQYsFZJ4gM6V/ScR+fcNLjRVTqC9vhwucbQbjtW9XROTGixbi6P1XnxZYIfYY/vthmVoXWErFHLAMoGrCz7UBGJW0KLn7PdMUXYBjcRqJYe+4D/I2VYW0lIpLOBkrgjrcrbHtNN/0vH38fGyNPhbMzLccW+Tqo3xYzqobZxenetGqBon1tI06pDOrTLn6djWYhXdZlqNFpXXY/C8DnZKwSejoPER6L5SAGK0RuDKxROrHqNXw3lUsIuhRpHl83jVXbvg+wT9LxcgODN738IbttbxOeXI7TO8MJwnF0RcQqwXJgg4g6lwDP9eG4eZ5DkK09w==;31:XbLZ42S1mgULCldfxD4tdswCKMK1cS7vfLD+FG9nWiDnId97lqaiEjqhMJKODPQ6D2wqtFthn6QmcsMJdibizsyvlxn8M7Wk/R+nn1Te+T4cT2ngQ4M67NizCLL2r8XnhNj+mOss4l84OUb5/R7JRLBVwJ1EVqvzsorjhJrP+5lC/yp+RCiNXQOM3u+FYorruWbYJRnKgyO6nss45/v195R/sk+gxArKezWR5DMLZGs=
X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic: MA1PR01MB0423:
X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-Test: UriScan:;
X-Microsoft-Antispam-PRVS:
     <MA1PR01MB042315699A93C8516E927B2DEA940@MA1PR01MB0423.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM>
X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-CFA-Test:
  BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(100000700101)(100105000095)(100000701101)(100105300095)(100000702101)(100105100095)(6040450)(2401047)(8121501046)(5005006)(93006095)(93001095)(10201501046)(3002001)(100000703101)(100105400095)(6002118)(6000006)(6041248)(20161123555025)(20161123564025)(20161123558100)(20161123560025)(201703131423075)(201703061421075)(20161123562025)(2016111802025)(6072148)(6043046)(201708071742011)(100000704101)(100105200095)(100000705101)(100105500095);SRVR:MA1PR01MB0423;
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
   1;MA1PR01MB0423;4:0/9bOsP2nGypeImKrp94rgcadobyGcmHZZJcrZkUYWm/njcJgwcAQCN9lUpXScM1V1xJ/OgUpsN0XumAc26tB9p2PxVh8ZlKLsUr6MekfDwIgTesUobWI0vz2H/dPFNXeyT3EB9c4kzNmL7eUFW1nzT6FbvB/T1EdCjWFT75Lys44X5fHMNv/7YyFYJMvNYFNi6+ZAVD0it+y54F+eHtUUfsCTW3evk+1+ifzP81C1MKGvgHgMXdexgwoZzp/zDL;23:OjwAxMC42eaZnBXh0jG8s6hWVMNwT3CLZvnFC1FffQMfC4yvFvyCPQwRol0ZIja9qcSK4H3e7okBP7qRbkbBmd92pefGIx1Zk8LERY0D3nZgrSyxljJCahO18B/96ypzTDc4pfMD4aU6wZskaNb09+jWANhMoUfSpjO6cWVmhLaaCSFtnF3oq6vVgdG20iQCAkV8vhAyH7kmV1pt17VLLzAmJe2qJ5IVb0Sr74FbXVc=;6:cnMNa1KjnOzQAMEYkQl2HnBDwhs0VUa2lJy07jV0iWa1fzIvHJKOUQcVCA1m17JigjidHTvENe91KEkVekLBJ9zVKi61ZVZ1oLTtx73RZdqUFJz8M2RYv0JcqYG36q+p53xrrW6vto/Y82nNWc30PIEBUcHUnyc9eiXugSjtgu08Rpj0RLJoxs2iHVzE3tskn1u45ll/c3J6+DCqAB3L+V1yWT76OvSjXBaI5GMAzvZQP3vjCzTz2SztNBKf8RDpVFsO1UcN6wuzNWIbRrPfwFH58VAlzf7Ua9jopR+nlPBVOsjnyS9Yrloz8qPIwl9mOEb4Tn1psCuxwTyhdLnHgQ==
X-Forefront-PRVS: 04238CD941
```

Comment: We are using o365 v2.0 APIs for creating meetings. Any pointers to circumvent this issue will be really helpful.